# If my walker is in base with a vehicle can it shoot AND attack?

Tags: warhammer-40k

My opponent rams my walker with his tank. No significant damage is incurred on either side, but my walker is immobilized and my walker fails to scratch the tank. What are my options on my turn:

- Can't shoot since technically I'm in combat, but can attack during my combat phase.
- Can shoot at the tank, and can attack in my combat phase.
- Can shoot at anything (in LOS) and can attack the tank in my combat phase.
- Can shoot at anything, but if I don't shoot the tank, I can't attack it in my combat phase.
- Something else?

If my walker isn't immobilized, what changes?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After much rules reading when encountering a similar situation w/ a drop pod I'm pretty sure that the most permissive answer is the correct one, specifically:

1. My unit being in base with an immobilized vehicle does not prevent that vehicle from shooting on it's turn (or firing Overwatch if it can).
2. My unit that is still in base with a vehicle can attack it in the combat phase.
3. On my turn, if my unit does not move (likely because it's immobilized), it can fire at another target and still attack the vehicle in the combat phase.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

**6th edition**

An immobilized walker cannot pivot (p.74)--so while overwatch is still allowed (p.84)--you are limited precisely moving targets within the 45 degree horizontal and vertical arc present at the time of immobilization.

Despite the base contact, the *tank* is not locked-in combat (p.76). This means the tank is a valid target during the shooting phase on your turn (from both the walker and other shooters), also provided that your immobilized walker can target the tank by being in it's current, unchangable 45 degree shooting arc.

The walker can engage in the assault phase with the tank right after being rammed (p.84). However, because it is immobilized, it would have one less attack to a minimum of one attack (p.84). This reduction will apply to the subsequent assault if you remain btb.

**7th edition**

7th edition seems to keep almost identical text regarding walkers, ramming, and overwatch.

> If my walker isn't immobilized, what changes?

Lots would change if your enemy wasn't a tank, but since it is a tank, the differences are fewer: **if you were *not* immobilized**, you could 1) walk away, 2) overwatch in all directions, 3) have all available assault attacks and 4) pivot and shoot at anybody within range.